# How to use alias and sum them together in select query

Tags: sql, database, select

I have the following queries below. I'd like to use the aliases and add them together but SQL does not allow that. Any suggestions on how I can go about this without repeating the queries again? Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT    
SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'Space' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As space,
SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'QPR' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As qpr,

(space + qpr) As result
FROM rg_fin As rg JOIN...../*query goes on*/
```

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap the query as a subquery

```
SELECT *,
  (space + qpr) As result 
FROM
(
  SELECT     
  SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'Space' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As space, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'QPR' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As qpr
  ....
 ) subquery
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
select 
  space, 
  qpr, 
  (space + qpr) As result
from (
  select
  SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'Space' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As space,
  SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'QPR' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As qpr,
  FROM rg_fin As rg JOIN...../*query goes on*/
) as a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the alias, then you will need to wrap the query inside of another query:

```
SELECT space
    , qpr
    , space + qpr as result
FROM
(
    SELECT    
    SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'Space' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As space,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'QPR' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As qpr,

    (space + qpr) As result
    FROM rg_fin As rg JOIN...../*query goes on*/
) x
```

Or if you do not need to use the alias, then you can just repeat the fields:

```
SELECT    
    SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'Space' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As space,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'QPR' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As qpr,

    (SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'Space' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) 
    + SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'QPR' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END)) As result
FROM rg_fin As rg JOIN...../*query goes on*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use derived table

```
SELECT 
    space,qpr,(space + qpr) As result 
FROM
(
SELECT     
SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'Space' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As space, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rg.category = 'QPR' THEN ((rg.score*20)) END) As qpr, 

(space + qpr) As result 
FROM rg_fin As rg JOIN...../*query goes on*/ 
) as t
```